# SyntaxError: Unexpected token node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I have a very strange error in this function

```
client.on("join", function(info){

    var data=decryptQuery(info.info);
    console.log("result " +data+ " string.");
    var dataP=Object.prototype.toString.call(data);
    console.log(dataP);
    var dataPar=JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("json " +dataPar+ " data.");

});
```

Return this output

```
  result {"a":2,"c":"qapa0ugc"}
  [object String]
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

So var data definitely is a string but

```
 console.log("result " +data+ " string.");
```

don't print the second part "string."

and

```
var dataPar=JSON.parse(data);
```

return syntax error but if i copy and paste string on

```
var dataPar=JSON.parse('{"a":2,"c":"qapa0ugc"}');
```

the script is ok

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(data.toString());`. That said, you shouldn't need to do that. It looks like something is wrong with your `decryptQuery` function, so we'll need to see that.

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof data)` to see what type data is. I thought data is not a string or correct json format.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I try it with no success

Comment: @Chen-TsuLin return string

Comment: What do you get from `(new Buffer(data)).toString()`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth {"a":2,"c":"qapa0ugc"}

Comment: Sorry, forgot a key part `(new Buffer(data)).toString('hex')`

Comment: @loganfsmyth 7b2261223a322c2263223a227161706130756763227d00000000000000000000

Comment: You have a bunch of null bytes at the end of your string. There must be a bug in your `decryptQuery` implementation or in the data in are decrypting.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes it is true a bug on decryptQuery